# How to integrate Azure IOT Hub with Ionic Mobile app?

Tags: azure, ionic-framework, notifications

I need to implement Notifications in my Ionic Application for Android. For that we have set up Azure IOT Hub where the device should get registered and from there, we can send messages to the device and vice versa (from the device to the cloud).

Now, I have gone through lots of links in the google regarding plugins for azure in Ionic, i tried them but in vain. I need to do two things

1. Register the device ID with the Azure IOT Hub
2. Send Notification in the Azure IOT Hub using that device ID, so that I can receive it in the device.

I have gone through

1. https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-node
2. https://github.com/derek82511/cordova-azure-notification-hubs

None of them helped me to register device to the IOT Hub. Can some one guide me in the right direction. I need to know the process how to connect the Azure IOT Hub with my Ionic mobile app for Android.

Code:

```
var iothub = require('azure-iothub'); 
var connectionString = config.hubConnectionString;

      var registry = iothub.Registry.fromConnectionString(connectionString);

      // Create a new device
      var device = {
      deviceId: uuid
      };

      registry.create(device, function(err, deviceInfo, res) {
          if (err) {
            console.log( ' error: ' + err.toString());
            this.showAlert('Create Device Error',err.toString());
          }
          if (res) {
            console.log(' status: ' + res.statusCode + ' ' + res.statusMessage);
            this.showAlert('Create Device Success Response',`status: ${res.statusCode} ${res.statusMessage}`);
          }
          if (deviceInfo) {
            console.log(' device info: ' + JSON.stringify(deviceInfo));
            this.showAlert('Device Info',JSON.stringify(deviceInfo));
          }
      });

      //var clientFromConnectionString = require('azure-iot-device-http').clientFromConnectionString;
      //var Message = require('azure-iot-device').Message;

      var connectionString = config.hubConnectionString;

      var client = clientFromConnectionString(connectionString);

      var connectCallback = function (err) {
        if (err) {
          console.error('Could not connect: ' + err);
          this.showAlert('HTTP Connection Error',err.toString());

        } else {
          console.log('Client connected');
          var message = new Message('some data from my device');
          client.sendEvent(message, function (err) {
            if (err) {
              console.log(err.toString());
              this.showAlert('HTTP Send IOT Message Error',err.toString());
            }
          });

          client.on('message', function (msg) { 
            console.log(msg); 
            this.showAlert('IOT Received Message',msg);
            client.complete(msg, function () {
              console.log('completed');
            });
          }); 
        }
      };

      client.open(connectCallback);
```

Comment: Is this about notifications only? Maybe Azure Notification Hubs is a better, less complex option? As for device to cloud messaging you could use Visual Studio App Center or Application Insights (if it's telemetry), else maybe Event Hubs.

Comment: We need bi directional thats why Azure IOT Hub and not Notification Hub.

Comment: @evilSnobu please see the below code that i tried with

Comment: that one is wrong `var connectionString = config.hubConnectionString;` You need to use the connection string for the device. You get the conn string back in the response when you create the device above, in `deviceInfo`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the IoT Hub *Service* SDK: https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-iothub

This example is from that link and shows how to use the device registry to create a new device.

```
var iothub = require('azure-iothub');

var connectionString = '[IoT Connection String]';

var registry = iothub.Registry.fromConnectionString(connectionString);

// Create a new device
var device = {
deviceId: 'sample-device-' + Date.now()
};

registry.create(device, function(err, deviceInfo, res) {
    if (err) console.log('error: ' + err.toString());
    if (res) console.log('status: ' + res.statusCode + ' ' + res.statusMessage);
    if (deviceInfo) console.log('device info: ' + JSON.stringify(deviceInfo));
});
```

Comment: "nothing happening" is not an error description to go on... what error are you getting? did you use the correct connection string (iothubowner)?

Comment: I have put debug points and alerts for each of these response mentioned to create the device. But the application is not responding to these debug points. Not sure what may be the issue

Comment: there is actually an error in the example I pasted above. the `op + ` needs to be removed. then it works fine for me. just tested. I updated to code above

Comment: So tested means you have an ionic project where you installed the following modules and got a success for the registration 

npm install azure-iothub

Because the code that you shared irrespective of that op removal , mine when installed in device does not respond.

Comment: dude, do not post your connection string online!! Please change the keys immediately!

Comment: Since you haven't posted any other code, we cannot help you, why the code above does not work for you

Comment: Any help on this please

Comment: I am getting CORS issue for the registration (create device) section. Can anyone guide me on this.

Comment: @evilSnobu I am getting multiple issues, once is web socket hand shake not happening error code 400 and the second problem is CORS issue. Need a little guidance on it